# localdb ((localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB) is not listed in Visual Studio IDE 2022 SQL Server Explorer

Tags: sql-server, blazor-server-side, visual-studio-2022, sql-server-2019-express

I recently installed Visual Studio IDE 2022 Version 17.6.2 and created a new Blazor Server Project targeting .NET 7.

For some reasons, unknown to me, the localdb is not listed under SQL Server on the SQL Server Explorer. I tried the following:

1. **Repair Visual Studio IDE.**
2. **Check Registry for localdb instances.**
3. **Checked the Visual Studio Installer and can see that SQL Server Express 2019 LocalDB is added and downloaded.**
4. **Tried to create a DB using EF Core but I get an error that says: SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.**
5. I ran "sqllocaldb info" in command prompt to see what databases are there on my device: **MSSQLLocalDB** and **ProjectModels**.

What could be the problem because this is my first time seeing this error.

I have attached images to this. If anyone has ever encountered this problem please explain how you overcame it. This is a new Blazor Server Project.

1. VS: *Visual Studio IDE 2022 Version 17.6.2*
2. OS: *Windows 11 Pro Version 22H2*

Thanks.

**ATTACHMENTS:**

[image: Error]

[image: Registry values]

[image: Nothing under SQL Server]

[image: SQL Server Express 2019 LocalDB is correctly installed]

[image: databases on my device]

Comment: "Failed to start" is telling you that it exists but, well, failed to start. Check the event viewer and the LocalDB error log (`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\mssqllocaldb\error.log`).

Comment: If you `SqlLocalDb.exe info MSSQLLocalDB` and `SqlLocalDb.exe info ProjectModels` have you started any of the instances yet? Ref: [SqlLocalDB utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: good question. the instances were stopped and I tried to start them but the error said cannot start automatic instances, I deleted the localdb instance and tried to create it and the error says  SQL Server process failed to start. I am looking around to understand more of this.

Comment: Check the error logs as mentioned

Answer (score 1):

I checked the error logs and saw a message stating something like “there have been 256 misaligned log IOs which required falling back to synchronous IO”.

I searched and found out that the error is usually associated with Windows 11 and Modern SSD. Windows 11 doesn’t behave the same way as Windows 10 when it comes to disk sector sizes on modern SSDs.

This article talked about how to troubleshoot OS 4KB disk sector size issues:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/database-file-operations/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size

error is solved.

Comment: Yes you need to (and should have anyway) initialized your SSD using 4k sectors. Gonna be difficult to change now unless you want to reformat your drive.

Comment: True. Had I known this. Had no idea.